# Recursive Solution for a simple knapsack Java version

Tags: java, recursion, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve this problem recursively.
 Assume an array: `int [] weights = {11,8,7,6,5};`
 The question: Find the combinations that give capacity of 20, in this case `(8,7,5)`.
 My Approach: The idea is to start with 11, and update the capacity to `20-11 = 9`, then look in `[8,7,6,5]`. Not there. Next step, I look for 8, update capacity to 20-8 = 12, and look for this capacity in `[7,6,5]`.. `(7+5 = 12)` so `(8,7,5)` is good, and so forth. Here is what I tried so far, but I am not quite there.

```
public class KnapSack {

int [] weights = {11,8,7,6,5};
int target = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new KnapSack().go();

}

void go(){

    solve(0,target);
}

void solve(int start,int target){

    System.out.println("Entering: target= "+target + " index: "+ start);
    if(target ==0)
        return;
    else{

        int total = 0;
        for(int i=start; i<weights.length; i++){

            //Combination worked
            if(weights[i]== target){
                System.out.println("Reached capacity!");
            }
            //combination exceeded
            else if(weights[i]> target){
                continue;
            }

            total += weights[i];

            solve(++start, target-weights[i]);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen for the weights { 10, 11, 2, 3, 5, 9} ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the idea to do this function recursively by advancing the start index and adjusting target (weight)

Comment: There are two possible ways to get to 20: 10+5+3+2 and 11+9. Does it matter which one you report?

Comment: No you are missing the point, the question is to find the combinations in original array, in this case only only 8,7,5 would give you a 20.

Comment: I guess your program should work for other inputs too - in your exaple, there is a unique solution. What is supposed to happen, if there are multiple solutions? Also your input list is sorted. Is this necessary for your algorithm?